# mysql gem install can't find ri/rdoc definitions OS X 10.6.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I installed the ruby gem for mysql and it looks like it installed correctly except for the documentation.

I reviewed http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-ruby/587057-gem-install-mysql-returns-list-no-definition-xyz.html but it didn't help.

Some notes, I am running on a 32-bit intel processor. Mac os x 10.6.1

```
Mac-Shaun:usr shaun$ sudo gem install mysql
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1...

No definition for next_result

No definition for field_name

..
..
More No Definitions.
..
..
```

[1]: http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-ruby/587057-gem-install-mysql-returns-list-no-definition-xyz.html "some posts in comp.lang.ruby" that match my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgraded to Snow Leopard or this is your first time installing rails on your Mac, you need to do some prep work.

First, all Intel based Macs are 64 bit. You need to install the 64 bit version of MySQL. If you have installed the 32 bit version, you will need to remove it.

Second, you will have to install XCode bundled with Snow Leopard. This is available on the Snow Leopard install disk.

Finally, if you have upgraded from Leopard to Snow Leopard and installed your own version of ruby on Leopard, you need to remove it. Snow Leopard is bundled with Ruby 1.8.7, and having multiple versions of ruby will cause conflicts.

I've documented the whole process on [my blog](http://www.nickonsoftware.com/?p=132).

Comment: I actually have the 32 bit version of intell mac (first intell mac was Core Duo, a 32-bit machine)

Comment: Then you are going to have to make sure that you don't have multiple versions of the ruby interpreter on the machine. If you have a version of ruby installed at /usr/local/bin/ruby chances are it is causing problems with the bundled version of Ruby that comes with Snow Leopard.

Comment: i'll check that out - where would the bundled version come from?